# Equivalent of Bash "!!" in IPython?

Tags: python, ipython

I'm looking for a functionality similar to Bash' `!!`.

In Bash, if you type `!!`, it replaces it with the last command you typed. For example, if you type `which deactivate`, and then `cat $(!!)`, the second command will be reformatted into `cat $(which deactivate)`.

In IPython typing `!!` leaves you with an empty list, which I suspect is trying to pass me a list of outputs from two empty-string shell commands.

Is there a similar way of formatting last command into the newly typed one in IPython?

Comment: While this does not re-execute the last command, you can use the last and next-to-last result with `_` and `__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab any previous input in IPython by referencing the input number:

```
In [4]: 'hello'
Out[4]: 'hello'

In [5]: In[4]
Out[5]: "'hello'"
```

If you want to grab the previous input to the current line, you can use `_i` or `In[-2]` ( `-1` references the current input):

```
In [6]: In[-2]
Out[6]: 'In[4]'

In [7]: _i
Out[7]: 'In[-2]'
```

Comment: You can also use `_i` for the last input @Błażej

Comment: @Jon, I did not know that.  I will update the answer.